# How to check the terms in single custom post type template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, single

I have custom post type called **events** it has **event_type taxonomy** with two **terms namely past-events, upcoming-events**. I want to check my single post's term whether it's under past-events or upcoming-events
Based on that i can display message.
Thank you All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then [`has_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) should be solution for your problem...

```
if ( has_term( 'past-events', 'event_type' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hi Krzysiek Dróżdż Thanks for the answer that works fine.